# What is the difference between HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_FORWARDED

Tags: http

I have been looking for a way to find the IP Address of the client and I've found both of these HTTP Headers.  From what I've found they are the same thing, but HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR seems more widely used.  Do any of you know what the difference is and if I am going to have to check both of these?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`X-Forwarded-For` header is not part of RFC, hence different implementation by proxy servers.
You should not rely on that value since it can be spoofed or simply not sent by proxy.

If it is important and you can afford to do it you should force requests through HTTPS and look up `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: The problem with Remote_Addr is that if the user goes through a proxy, this will turn the proxy address, not the client address.

Comment: True for HTTP.
But if you use HTTPS your REMOTE_ADDR will hold the actual client address even if it is routed through a proxy.

Comment: this doesn't make sense to me. Since HTTPS is encrypted how does that data get encapsulated into the header? My understanding is that this is only true if SSL is terminated at the proxy, so that the proxy can decrypt the headers and attach the necessary information...

Comment: @BojanG no, even in HTTPS it still returns proxy data, tried using both in HTTPS site.

Comment: But not it would seem for the OWIN 'server.RemoteIpAddress' environment value (- at least in older implementations such as for MVC5).